# How to visualize a graph having multiple edge types in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Though Alloy has a graph module, the module does not distinguish different edge types.

I make a graph having multiple edge types in Alloy. But the visualization is against intuition.

```
sig Node { to : Node -> lone Edge}

abstract sig Edge {}
sig VisibleEdge , HiddenEdge extends Edge{}

fact{
all n : Node | not n in n.^(to.Edge) // acyclicity
all e : Edge  | e in Node.(Node.to)
lone VisibleEdge 
lone HiddenEdge
}

run {#to > 2 } for 5
```

[image]

The problem with the visualization is that it connects nodes to edges, but intuitively, we want to see nodes connect to nodes.

Though I could change the `to : Node -> lone Edge` to `to : Edge -> Node`, but then it seems impossible to write the acyclicity constraint in a transitive way.

Is there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this issue, when using `to : Edge -> Node` (or better: `to : Edge lone -> Node`), is to consider a binary relation between nodes that contains all pairs of connected nodes, regardless of the edge type. Then, in the Visualizer, you can hide `to` and show `edges`. The acyclicity condition is also easier to write:

```
fun edges : Node -> Node { { n1, n2: Node | some n1.to.n2 } }
fact { all n : Node | n not in n.^edges }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an advanced thought. BTW, is `to : Edge lone -> Node` synonymous to `to : Edge -> lone Node`? I did not know `lone` can be on the left side of `->`.

Comment: In what you wrote the multiplicity is not on the same relation so, here, it doesn't mean the same thing. Basically, when considering a multiplicity, you quantify all other columns universally, and apply the multiplicity to the composition of the said columns with the field. For instance, `sig Node { to : Edge lone -> Node }` yields `all m: Node, n: Node | lone m.to.n`. While `sig Node { to : Edge -> lone Node }` yields `all m: Node, e: Edge | lone m.to[e]`. If there are several multiplicities, you repeat that for every column with a multiplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Grayswandyr's answer, I updated my code as following,

```
sig Node { 
to : Edge lone ->  Node
}

abstract sig Edge {}
sig VisibleEdge , HiddenEdge extends Edge{}

fun edges : Node -> Node { { n1, n2: Node | some n1.to.n2 } }
fact { all n : Node | n not in n.^edges }

fact{
//all n : Node | not n in n.^(to.Edge) // acyclicity
all e : Edge  | #(e.(Node.to)) = 1
}

run {#to > 2 } for 5
```

The visualization now is as expected.

[image]